# How to migrate my Apache server to Nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have an Apache server on Ubunu 18.04 with a Drupal 8 site that I want to migrate to Nginx and PHP7.3-FPM.

This is the only site on the server. I do not know Nginx at all.

I deleted Apache with the following command :

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge apache2*
```

Here is the configuration I had on Apache :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin contact@domaine.com
   ServerName domaine.com
   ServerAlias www.domaine.com
   Protocols h2 http/1.1
   DocumentRoot /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/

   <Directory /var/www/www-domaine-com/web>
      Options +Includes -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
   </FilesMatch>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's how I installed Nginx :

```
sudo apt install nginx
sudo ufw allow in "Nginx HTTP"
```

I am testing the IP address of my server and the Nginx page is displayed.

```
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Here is my Nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen :80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domaine.com www.domaine.com;

    root   /var/www/www-domaine-com/web;
    index  index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I create a symbolic link of my new configuration :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.domaine.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

I test my configuration :

```
sudo nginx -t
```

This message is displayed :

```
nginx: [emerg] no host in ":80" of the "listen" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www-domaine-com:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: What file is that nginx configuration from? Does `nginx -t` return any errors? Regarding the connection refused error, check the output of `ss -tnlp` on your server to confirm that nginx is started and listening.

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/install-and-configure-nginx-and-php-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: @fukawi2 I updated my question

Comment: @Dextro67 I followed the tutorial and I have this error "The provided host name is not valid for this server."

Comment: @fgtr You missed my first question - which file is your nginx snippet from? `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or a file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`?  Also, are your file/directory permissions set to allow `nginx` user access to `/var/www/html/www-s1biose-com/web`?

Comment: @fukawi2 "/etc/nginx/sites-available/www-s1biose-com" Permissions for the "web" folder are at www-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message shows you have an error in the specified line of your nginx configuration.

```
    listen :80;
```

This is a typo; it should appear as:

```
    listen 80;
```

Comment: on the ip address I have the same error as in my question. On the domain name I have the error `404 Not Found
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 2):

Based on our short dicussion in the comments, my best guess is that there is another `server` block in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` that is acting as the default server so when you access it by IP, nginx serves that `server` block instead of the one you've configured in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www-s1biose-com`.  You can either remove that `server` block from `nginx.conf`, or just remove `default_server` from the `server_name` directive in it and add `default_server` to `server_name` in your configuration.

You don't mention what distribution you're using, but also check that the `nginx.conf` file is including files from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`. CentOS doesn't by default, I'm not sure about Ubuntu/Debian and others.

As to why you get a connection refused when accessing by the domain name (which should work as it matches the `server_name` directive in your config), check that your DNS resolution is pointing to the right IP address, and check that your browser isn't trying HTTPS instead of HTTP as you haven't configured HTTPS.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and I only deleted the default server with the command line `sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`. The domain name points well to the server puique I have a 404 error

Comment: I updated my question